# I want to convert razor syntax into comma shape " " so I will be able to render div dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, string-formatting

**I want to convert RazorSyntax into concatenation (StringFormat) in JavaScript**

Asp.Net Mvc

```
              @Html.TextBox("questionChoice", null, new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })
```

JavaScript

```
     var answersDiv = " <div class='row myrow' >" +
         "<div class='col-md-5'>" +
              @Html.TextBox('questionChoice', null, new { @required = 'required', @class = 'form-control' }) +
            "</div>" +
       " <div class='col-md-2 mt-1'> " +
              " <label style='font-weight:normal'> <label><input type='checkbox'  name='isCorrect'>Option 1</label> " +
        " </div> " +
```

**same sentence output show**

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: brother I want to convert razor syntax into comma shape " " so I will be able to render div dynamically with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Switch the quotes and apostrophes

```
var answersDiv = ' <div class="row myrow" >' +
     '<div class="col-md-5">' +
          '@Html.TextBox("questionChoice", null, new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control" })' +
        '</div>' +
   ' <div class="col-md-2 mt-1"> ' +
          ' <label style="font-weight:normal"> <label><input type="checkbox"  name="isCorrect">Option 1</label> ' +
    '</div>' +
```